# React map not rendering array

Tags: reactjs, firebase

After obtaining a data, I take a photo of the user from the users table with the user's ids, I can access all the data without any problem and I can see all of them with console.log. But it doesn't render.
How can i solve this problem ? Thank you.

```
export default function MentionInput(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(UsePeopleModuleContext);
  const [decisionUserRole, setDecisionUserRole] = useContext(
    UseDecisionUserRoleContext
  );
  const { isConsulted, isResponsible, isApprover, isCreator } =
    decisionUserRole;
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const { users, currentWorkspace, activeDecision, setActiveDecision } =
    useWorkspace();
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const userMentionData = users.map((myUser) => ({
    id: myUser.userId,
    value: myUser.userId,
    displayName: `${myUser.displayName}`,
    label: `${myUser.displayName}`,
  }));
  const propsData = props;

  useEffect(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const people = await usersModule.getPeople(
      currentWorkspace,
      activeDecision.id
    );
    const datas = [];
    if (propsData.field === 'consulted') {
      people.consulted.map((consulted) => {
        console.log('CONSULTED =>', consulted);
        userdb.getUser(consulted.id).then((user) => {
          const photoURL = user.photoURL;
          datas.push({
            id: consulted.id,
            value: consulted.id,
            displayName: `${user.displayName}`,
            label: `${user.displayName}`,
            photoURL: photoURL !== undefined ? photoURL : '',
          });
        });
      });
      console.log('DATAS =>', datas);
      setValue(datas);

      setLoading(false);
    } else if (propsData.field === 'approver') {
      const user = await userdb.getUser(people.approver.id);
      const photoURL = user.photoURL;
      setValue([{ ...people.approver, photoURL: photoURL }]);
      setLoading(false);
    } else if (propsData.field === 'responsible') {
      //await userdb.getUser
      const user = await userdb.getUser(people.responsible.id);
      const photoURL = user.photoURL;
      setValue([{ ...people.responsible, photoURL: photoURL }]);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    !loading &&
    (isCreator || !isResponsible ? (
      <Box w="100%">
        <Select
          isMulti={
            props.field === 'consulted'
              ? true
              : props.field === 'approver'
              ? false
              : props.field === 'responsible'
              ? false
              : true
          }
          name=""
          options={userMentionData}
          placeholder="Assign people"
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          size="sm"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </Box>
    ) : (
      <Box w="100%" ml="10px">
        <Wrap>
          {value?.map((item, index) =>
            item !== undefined ? (
              <WrapItem key={index}>
                <Tag
                  size="md"
                  borderRadius="lg"
                  ml={index === 0 ? 0 : 2}
                  colorScheme="gray"
                >
                  <Avatar
                    size="xs"
                    name={
                      item?.displayName !== undefined &&
                      item?.displayName.toLowerCase()
                    }
                    ml={-3}
                    mr={2}
                    src={item.photoURL}
                  />

                  <TagLabel>{item?.displayName}</TagLabel>
                </Tag>
              </WrapItem>
            ) : null
          )}
        </Wrap>
      </Box>
    ))
  );
}
```

**userdb.getUser:  it works beautifully.**

```
getUser: async (userId) => {
    const q = query(doc(db, 'user', userId));
    const getData = await getDoc(q);
    if (getData.exists()) {
      return getData.data();
    }
  },
```

[image: console.log]

[image: No render]
As you can see from the screenshots, the data comes out fine, but the  component does not render.

Comment: Looks like you're setting the photoURL in the `then` block, which doesn't call `setValue`. What that means is that you're updating the object directly without telling React, so it doesn't know to re-render the page. Try moving the state updates under your `DATAS =>` logging statement up into the `then` block.

Comment: Hey @samuei can you explain with code please,  I couldn't figure out where to move state.

Answer (score -1):

i update my setState function , the question solved.

```
if (propsData.field === 'consulted') {
      const datas = [];
      people.consulted.map((consulted) => {
        userdb.getUser(consulted.id).then((user) => {
          const photoURL = user.photoURL;
          setValue((value) => [
            ...value,
            {
              id: consulted.id,
              value: consulted.id,
              displayName: `${user.displayName}`,
              label: `${user.displayName}`,
              photoURL: photoURL !== undefined ? photoURL : '',
            },
          ]);
        });
      });
      setLoading(false);
    }
```